# What's the difference between application.start() and application.run()

Tags: nativescript

I'm getting this message in my NativeScript JavaScript app:

```
application.start() is deprecated; use application.run() instead
```

If I simply replace

```
application.start({ moduleName: "views/main-page" });
```

with

```
application.run({ moduleName: "views/main-page" });
```

elements on my main view are missing.  It looks like there's more I need to do, but my searches so far haven't yielded results.

I understand the rationale from https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#application-run, it just looks like more is needed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you create the application variable first i.e. `let application = require("tns-core-modules/application");`

Comment: @Sflagg - yes I did.  The app opens, but its visibly different.  For example, I have the name of the app with an icon at the top of the screen.  The icon is there, the text is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application.start()` was used prior to {N} v4.x, it used to create a `Frame` and host your `Page` within that. It was not possible to have more than one `Frame` in your application at those times.

Since v4.x, we have `application.run()` that allows you to set any View as root for your application and you are now allowed to use any number of `Frame`s in your application.

If you are using `application.run({ moduleName: "views/main-page" });` then `main-page` should have a `Frame` at root level or any View except Page.

Checkout the [v4.0 release blog](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-4.0-is-out) for more info.